# Cakephp 2.x to 3 migration, where does the folder app/Lib/Routing with the custom routeClass go to?

Tags: routes, cakephp-3.0

How can I set up a custom routeClass as in Cakephp 2.x? The Route extension is located inside the app/Lib/Routing directory in Cakephp 2.x. Where do I have to place it in Cakephp 3?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create this folder :  /Lib/Routing/Route
and use :

```
Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes

if you want some example take a look in the deep heart of cakephp

vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Route

Answer (score 0):

In 3.x dont put the Routing in Lib just put it in the src of plugin or app.

2.x - https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-dynamic-route

```
App::uses('FancyRoute', 'DynamicRoute.Lib/Routing/Route');
FancyRoute::connect();
```

3.x

```
$routes->connect('/stuff/:slug',
['controller' => 'SomeThings', 'action' => 'view'], ['routeClass' =>
'SomeThings.FancyRoute']);
```

then its up to the match & parse methods within the Custom route. Presently I have more joy with regex to define the matches of passed slugs